# Perform DoubleClick on element that have that

Tags: javascript, firefox

looks here: [image]

that from One page that show me that element have event of doubleclick "dblclick"

but when i try to perform it from console:

[image]

Comment: Unless you're using jQuery or some other framework, you can't fire an event like that. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399215/how-to-programmatically-fire-a-dblclick-event-defined-with-addeventlistener

Comment: noahnu epascarello  your both answer are works :)
write your both i will mark as i wanted..
i took the @noahnu answer for my project cause i use powershell but the problem was perform dbclick :)
and in his way is more easy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dblclick is not a method, it is a type of event.
Let's say you have a button, and you wanted to manually fire that event. You could do so like this.

```
<button id='myButton'>Click Me!</button>
```

Now you can do this

```
var evt = new Event('dblclick');
var button = document.getElementById('myButton');
// This is where the magic happens
button.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

This manually fires the dblclick event.
You must call 'dispatchEvent' on a dom node, and it takes an 'Event' object.

For your use case, just replace the 'button' element with your own 'a' variable, and it should work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

That answer works as well:

thank you both guys

noahnu and  epascarello

```
var event; // The custom event that will be created

  if (document.createEvent) {
    event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    event.initEvent("dblclick", true, true);
  } else {
    event = document.createEventObject();
    event.eventType = "dblclick";
  }

  event.eventName = "dblclick";

  if (document.createEvent) {
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
  } else {
    element.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);
  }
```